# Add many shapefile in neo4j spatial

Tags: neo4j, spatial

I have to build a database  in neo4j spatial with spatial.addWKTLayer(layerName, 'geometry') and spatial.importShapefileToLayer(layerName, SHP_file) command. I have many shapefile (country.shp, cities.shp, roads.shp, building.shp...)  country and cities ara polygons type, roads are linestring type, building are point type.
My question is: I have to create a spatial layer for each shapefile or one layer for all shapefiles?